# Comparar elementos de dos arrays diferentes con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de comparar elementos de dos arrays, quiero que si la suma de alguno de los elementos del primer array con la suma de alguno los elementos del segundo array me da 7 me muestre las parejas de números que dan ese resultado, quiero hacer esto con for, anidé dos for pero no me arroja nada en absoluto no se si deba recorrerlos por aparte o algo así.

Gracias por la ayuda

```
let firstArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let secondArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

for(i=0; i<firstArray.length; i++){
   for(i=0; i<secondArray.length; i++){
       if(firstArray[i] + secondArray[i] == 7){
        console.log(firstArray[i], secondArray[i]);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Necesitas dos variables distintas para recorrer cada arreglo

Comment: si es cierto, que distraído soy, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

era una pregunta muy sencilla pero el primer error era que usted definió dos for con la mismas variable
en es caso le cambiar el segundo for I a f

y tiene que imprimir los dos números realizando la suma

```js
let firstArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let secondArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

for(i=0; i<firstArray.length; i++){
   for(f=0; f<secondArray.length; f++){
       if( (firstArray[i] + secondArray[f]) == 7){
        console.log(firstArray[i]+' + '+ secondArray[f] +'='+ (firstArray[i] + secondArray[f])  );
       }
   }
}
```